# Routing a subnet to OpenVPN Client (tcpdump shows no icmp)

Tags: centos, debian, iptables, routing

I have an OpenVPN server with the network 172.24.24.0/29 (IP: 172.24.24.1).
A Raspberry (172.24.24.2) is connected to this OpenVPN server.

The Raspberry has access to my local network 192.168.2.0/24 and should allow the OpenVPN server access to this network via NAT.

Kernel forwarding is enabled on both.

- Ping from OpenVPN server to Raspberry works vice versa
- Ping from Raspberry to local LAN works vice versa
- Ping from OpenVPN server to local LAN does not work

**OpenVPN server:**

```
[root@openvpn ~]# ip route
172.24.24.0/29 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.24.24.1
192.168.2.0/24 via 172.24.24.2 dev tun1

[root@openvpn ~]# ip route get 192.168.2.101
192.168.2.101 via 172.24.24.2 dev tun1  src 172.24.24.1
```

Ping 192.168.2.101 from OpenVPN server.
On the Raspberry, however, no packets are displayed at the interface with `tcpdump`. But `tcpdump` displays the outgoing packets:

```
[root@openvpn ~]# tcpdump -ni tun1 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
20:10:00.610156 IP 172.24.24.1 > 192.168.2.101: ICMP echo request, id 3413, seq 1, length 64
20:10:01.616216 IP 172.24.24.1 > 192.168.2.101: ICMP echo request, id 3413, seq 2, length 64
```

**Raspberry**

- VPN-IP: 172.24.24.2 (tun0)
- Local LAN: 192.168.2.101 (eth0)

iptables: (policy ACCEPT for all chains)

```
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 172.24.24.0/29 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Routing table

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
172.24.24.0/29 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.24.24.2
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.101
```

I initially thought that it is due to an iptables rule or to the NAT. That no packages arrive at the tun0 interface of the Raspberry I find very unusual and guess there the mistake.

Where could the mistake be in this setup? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What is the routing table at Raspberry?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Routing table added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the solution](http://www.synology-forum.de/entry.html?66-Entfernte-und-lokale-Netze-mit-OpenVPN-verbinden) in a German Synology forum.
Further settings on the OpenVPN server are necessary. The configuration can be found here: ["Including multiple machines on the client side when using a routed VPN (dev tun)"](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope).